# How exactly sbt figures out task names?

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose there's something like this in `build.sbt`

```
val printMessage = taskKey[Unit]("Simple task")

printMessage := {
    println("Hello")
}
```

How sbt figures out that this task is called `printMessage` and makes it available in CLI when there is no string with that text? I would understand if the code was something like `val printMessage = taskKey[Unit]("printMessage", "description")` but this really baffles me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SBT has a [macro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/9ee8299383afb8c64f175acd9d3cb8648be519b6/main/settings/src/main/scala/sbt/std/KeyMacro.scala#L22), `sbt.std.KeyMacro.taskKeyImpl` which takes a `String` description and infers the task name from the defining val's name.

This macro is [aliased](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/9ee8299383afb8c64f175acd9d3cb8648be519b6/sbt/src/main/scala/package.scala#L46) to `taskKey[T]` in the sbt package object.

So when you call `taskKey[Unit]("SimpleTask")`, that's expanded to a macro that finds the val `printMessage` and uses that to infer the task key's name.